# Extract int value from json and multiply by specific value to sum in custom column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4, jsonb-array-elements

Good day

please, help with this.
I have table "tickets" with column printer_catalog:
records from 1st row of column printer_catalog

```
{"Refueling::HP 1005 (65gr)::2 pcs","Cylinder replacement::HP 1005::4 pcs"}
```

I need 2nd column with total sum which sums the services.
for example:

if "Refueling::HP 1005 (65gr)" then multiply 2 pcs by 3:

2 * 3 = 6

if "Cylinder replacement::HP 1005" then multiply 4 pcs by 3:

4 * 3 = 12

and sum this values 12 + 6 = 18, and show 18 in 2nd custom column.

Comment: Try using  a combination of PostgreSQL functions to process the JSONB array elements, extract the necessary parts of the string, perform conditional checks, and then aggregate the results.

Comment: The way @TSCAmerica.com showed is correct. But this problem is a hell of inefficiency! You should definitely think about not doing it that way! Please normalize your database. Don't store in JSON, don't separate different fields by some string delimiters and don't store numeral values with their units! So much points that might get wrong here, so much points that need sanitizing and validating. Everything will need extra performance.